# Android read image from camera's sdcard with otg

Tags: usb-otg

[devices for test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtZ1e.jpg)

I would like to read images from camera's sdcard(e.g Canon or Nikon) to my Android App with an otg line.

I have learn the example of libaums(https://github.com/magnusja/libaums), but it just support USBMassStorageDevice, not support digital camera devices.

I have no C or C++ experience, so I have no idea about it.
Do you have some idea to help me!

Thanks!

Comment: can you tell me how you solve it. Thanks.